# How to cut two Posixct sequences using predefined levels

Tags: r, dplyr, posixct

I need to aggregate two POSIXct 5-min sequences into 10-min sequences.
In order to do this I want to create a 10-min key from both 5-min sequences such that both use the same levels.

I'm wondering if there is an R way of doing this?

Here is an example:

```
a = seq(as.POSIXct("2012-06-01 06:01"), by = "5 min", length.out = 24)
b = seq(as.POSIXct("2012-06-01 06:07"), by = "5 min", length.out = 24)

cut(a, "10 min")
cut(b, "10 min")
```

You'll notice seq a and b use different levels

Now you can do some trickery to fix this, but its not really nice

```r
b_adjusted = b-min(abs(min(as.POSIXct(cut(a, "10 min")))-b))
cut(b_adjusted, "10 min")
```

or

```r
keys = cut(c(a,b), "10 min")
a = keys[1:length(a)]
b = keys[(length(a)+1):(length(a)+length(b))]
```

This is just an example, my actual case involves >10 sequences.
Ideally i would be able to use cut with levels starting from the first round 10-min level eg if the first item in my sequence is 00:17 then the generated key is 00:10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe combine all the vectors and then generate 10 min sequence from `min` to `max` value.

```
library(lubridate)

combined_seq <- c(a, b)
lvls <- seq(floor_date(min(combined_seq), '10 mins'),
              ceiling_date(max(combined_seq), '10 mins'), by = '10 mins')
```

You can then use this `lvls` as levels in `cut`.

```
cut(a, levels)
cut(b, levels)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using base R we form a list of the inputs, `L`, and compute a list of vectors `L10` from it which we see have common sets of values if we use the data in the question; however, if that is not the general case we can create a set of levels `levs` from them giving a list of factors `L10f` with common levels.

```
min10.POSIXct <- function(x) {  # returns POSIXct arg truncated to 10 min
  as.POSIXct(600 * floor(as.numeric(a) %/% 600), origin = "1970-01-01")
}
L <- list(a, b)
L10 <- lapply(L, min10.POSIXct)

# empty result shows they have same values
length(setdiff(L10[[1]], L10[[2]]))
## [1] 0

rng <- range(do.call("range", L10))
levs <- format(seq(rng[1], rng[2], "10 min"))

L10f <- lapply(L10, factor, levs)
```

### Update

Have revised several times.